# How to make navbarText as an URL or clickable button

Tags: xpages

Seems it's just a static text. But I want to e.g. redirect to home page by clicking on navbarText label... Just adding "

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Workaround:
Create a CSS style class:

```
.navbarText {
   cursor:pointer;
}
```

Assign the class to the text element

Create a onClientLoad Javascript which uses jQuery:

```
$(".navbarText").click(function(){
   // do your redirect stuff here
});
```

If you don't use jQuery then you can also do this with Dojo (for which I can't provide code because I don't use Dojo).